# XCode can't find OpenSSL headers in /usr/include

Tags: xcode, macos, openssl, header-files, include

I'm trying to use standard system header files in my C++ XCode project:

```
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
```

The build fails and it complains:

```
"Openssl/bio.h: No such file or directory"
```

I added /usr/include to the "Header Search Paths" in Project settings, but that doesn't fix it.

I can fix it by adding the whole path like:

```
#include </usr/include/openssl/bio.h>
```

-- but the project is full of similar includes and I don't want to change all of them this way. Also, I feel I shouldn't have to do this.

Another way to fix it would be as another thread mentioned, which is to add /usr/include to *User* Header Search Paths. But if I do that, then I'd have to change all the angle brackets <> to quotes "", which again seems like a hack. I mean, these are standard system header files so I feel it should be something simple, not requiring these kinds of hacks.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Xcode uses the currently selected SDK as a base path, which it prefixes on to system includes. So if your SDK is `/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk` then it will look under `/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include` by default for system includes.

There are various possible workarounds - I would probably just put a symbolic link in `/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include` pointing at `/usr/include/openssl` but you can probably think of others now that you know the underlying problem.

Comment: thanks Paul, I ended up doing something similar! But I didn't understand why it worked. It makes sense now, thanks!

Comment: I cannot get this to work on xCode 5 with the iOS 7 sdk. It will find /usr/include/openssl but not openssl. Have spent way too many hours trying to fix this. I don't see the /Developer/SDKs folder in the current sdk. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @JPK: in Xcode 4 and 5 all the /Developer stuff got relocated inside Xcode.app.

Comment: @PaulR thanks - do you mind helping me figure out how to set my paths? I am not trying to be obtuse but I have really been banging my head against the wall with this. I am including an xCode project that builds openssl and crypto within my project, so I have multiple header paths that I am playing with for DAYS, and I am having the exact same problem you were having above. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, I did get it working (I figured out symlinking, which I had not previously used) but all for nought. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16461315/how-to-solve-this-error-bio-new-is-deprecated-in-cocoa

Comment: "What Apple has deprecated is using their OpenSSL headers and their OpenSSL dynamic library"

Comment: I want to understand your workaround. Can u tell me how to put the symbolic link and where?

Comment: When i build the app in Xcode5 it always warning like openssl/bio.h file not found.Can u help me?

Comment: @Ganesh: use `sudo ln -s ... ...` to set up a symbolic link between the required includes directory and the corresponding location in whatever SDK you are using. See `man ln`.

Answer (score 1):

It might depend on the fact that HFS(+) is case insensitive. The error message talks about "Openssl/bio.h" with capital "O", but you're specifying "openssl/bio.h" in the include and the path with /usr/include works.

I suspect that there's some "Openssl" (capital "O") directory in your include path, that gets used when looking for "openssl/bio.h". This wouldn't happen if HFS(+) were case sensitive from the very beginning (I know it's possible to have is case sensitive, but it's actually a PITA to use...)

Comment: Thanks for the response, polettix. The capital "O" is just XCode -- it always tries to be "proper" and starts things with capital letters, which more often than not serves only to confuse. But just to be sure, I did rename /usr/include/openssl to /usr/include/Openssl (I guess I could have symlinked it), but that didn't change anything :(

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to avoid having to specify paths on includes by simply *making sure to select **Create groups for any added folders** for the **Folders** option in the Add Files to Project dialog* which pops up when you're adding the files.

With the other option, Create folder reference for any added folders, I have to manually point it to the file via the full path (and the folder icons show up blue instead of the normal beige). Interestingly, even in this case, AutoComplete sees the file, but Xcode complains it can't find it.