# How to solve this error 'BIO_new' is deprecated in cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, macos, compiler-errors

I am new to Macintosh development. I have NSData+connection.m file. This file have more deprecated function like `BIO_new` , `BIO_write`, `BIO_get_mem_data` etc. The functions all encounter deprecated errors.

```
- (NSString *)base64Encoding
{
    BIO * mem = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    BIO * b64 = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());
    BIO_set_flags(b64, BIO_FLAGS_BASE64_NO_NL);
    mem = BIO_push(b64, mem);

    BIO_write(mem, [self bytes], [self length]);
    BIO_flush(mem);

    char * base64Pointer;
    long base64Length = BIO_get_mem_data(mem, &base64Pointer);

    NSString * base64String = [NSString stringWithCString:base64Pointer
                                               length:base64Length];

    BIO_free_all(mem);
    return base64String;
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: It's Mac, not MAC.  The latter either means Mandatory Access Control or Media Access Control depending on the context.

Comment: Apple deprecated OpenSSL in favor of its CoreCrypto (I believe it was CoreCrypto). There was a thread on an Apple developer message board about it. I think the discussion fell out of the WWDC developer conference in 2012 or so. The discussion was not public at the time - it was hidden under NDA.

Answer (score 4):

What Apple has deprecated is using *their* OpenSSL headers and *their* OpenSSL dynamic library. The reason is that OpenSSL's interface changes in incompatible ways even across minor revisions, so it's hard to keep up to date with bugfixes and security updates without breaking client code.

What you *can* do (and what I have done in the past) is [grab OpenSSL yourself](http://www.openssl.org/source/), use the functions from that version and bundle that with your application.

Comment: Thanks Graham Lee. I am using OSX 10.8.3.

Comment: Of course, if you ship OpenSSL yourself, you will need to ship application updates if one of its vulnerabilities affects you.

Comment: @alastair true, while if you _don't_ ship OpenSSL yourself, you get to take advantage of the updates that Apple aren't providing for you :)

Answer (score 3):

If your application targets Mac OS X 10.7 or higher, you could use [SecTransform](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/SecTransformPG/SecurityTransformsBasics/SecurityTransformsBasics.html) instead.

Worth noting as well that base64 has quite a few variants ([the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) lists no fewer than 13), which might make you wary of using other peoples' implementations of it unless they properly document their behaviour (IMO both OpenSSL and SecTransform fail to fully specify their behaviour in their documentation).

Answer (score 0):

> How to solve this error 'BIO_new' is deprecated in cocoa?

You solve this issue by *not* using Apple's version of OpenSSL located in `/usr/include` and `/usr/lib`. Its an old version - 0.9.8 - so its missing a number of features. Its loss will not be missed.

Instead, you should download, build and install the latest version of OpenSSL. You can download it from [OpenSSL: Source, Tarballs](http://www.openssl.org/source/).

Configure with the following (there's a more comprehensive list of options on the OpenSSL wiki at [Configure Options](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation#Configure_Options)).

```
$ export KERNEL_BITS=64
$ ./config no-ssl2 enable-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128 --openssldir=/usr/local
$ make all
$ sudo make install
```

`--openssldir=/usr/local` means `/usr/local/ssl` will be the base directory for the installation.

Later, when you compile and link, you perform the following:

- Add `/usr/local/ssl/include` ans a header search path (i.e., a `-I` option)
- Add `/usr/local/ssl/lib` ans a library search path (i.e., a `-L` option)

*If* you use `-L`, then be sure to use `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` when executing your program. Its like `LD_PRELOAD` on Linux. If you don't use `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`, then [`dyld`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dyld.1.html) will load the old, 0.9.8 version of OpenSSL located in `/usr/lib`; and not your updated, 1.0.1 version of OpenSSL located in `/usr/local/ssl/lib/`.

Better, omit `-L` and specify the full library paths.

- `/usr/local/ssl/lib/libssl.a`
- `/usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a`

This way you don't need to worry about `-L` and `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Things just work as expected.